# Why the custom scope bean is always return the same instance in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to implement the custom scope bean. I have been reading this content in the Spring Framework Doc about this. But when I write the code myself, I have confused. There are two threads, but they have got the same instance. I want to know the reason. The following example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
    <bean id="bean" class="com.example.demo.custom.scope.CustomScope" scope="custom">
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="thing" class="com.example.demo.custom.scope.Thing">
        <property name="customScope" ref="bean"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

```java
package com.example.demo.custom.scope;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope;

public class CustomScope {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomScope.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        method1();
    }

    private static void method1() {
        String path = "classpath:custom/scope/customScope.xml";
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation(path);
        Scope scope = new SimpleThreadScope();
        context.refresh();
        context.getBeanFactory().registerScope("custom", scope);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Thing thing = context.getBean("thing", Thing.class);
                    log.info("{}-{}-thing.hashCode:{},custom.hashCode:{}", Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                            scope.getConversationId(), thing.hashCode(), thing.getCustomScope().hashCode());
                }
            });
            thread.setName(String.valueOf(i));
//          thread.join();
            thread.start();
        }
        context.close();
    }
}
```

The log infomation is:

```
2020-11-05 17:06:50,469 INFO  [1] com.example.demo.custom.scope.CustomScope$1: 1-1-thing.hashCode:346204054,custom.hashCode:-475529550
2020-11-05 17:06:50,469 INFO  [0] com.example.demo.custom.scope.CustomScope$1: 0-0-thing.hashCode:346204054,custom.hashCode:-475529550
```

Comment: 1. You should register the scope before calling `refresh`, 2. scopes are implemented using proxies, you are seeing the hashcode of the proxy (which will always be the same).

Comment: @M.Deinum Is the `refresh` call really needed ? `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(path)` makes refresh not necessary.

Comment: @M.Deinum, @quasimodo00  Not yet. If calling `refresh` after register,Spring will thrown a `IllegalStateException`,that is `BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory`

Comment: Without the registratioj of the scope it simply isn't available. Instead write a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` register it and use that to register the custom scope, or as you are already using XML, use the preferred way (as shown in the spring documentation).

Comment: It's unavailable by using BeanFactoryPostProcessor.It looks like to the same result.Also,Spring document dosen't describe this section in detail. I want to get the thread scope, but only get the singleton scope.